# Set up Ubuntu FTP with root access to whole server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, root

I've been trying to set up Ubuntu 12.10 with FTP to give the A user access to read/write any file on the server.

I understand some people discourage root access for this, but at this stage I am more concerned with getting it to work first, and will address security concerns later.

Have tried a lot of guides online for vsftpd e.t.c but nothing is working.

Answer (score 3):

To make things easier and secure try setting up an SFTP connection.Its much easier.Install SSH.Choose SFTP in sitemanager in Filezilla, enter IP,username,password.You are done...

Answer (score 0):

If you already have vsftpd installed, try setting the following options

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
```

Restart vsftpd and it should work (using your root credentials).